# Converting html in string format to .docx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a html page where I read the file to a string and replace the content dynamically from database like following

```
try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/QuotationFormat.htm"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        result = result.Replace("<quotationno>", _list[0].quotation_no);
```

Now after replacing the content, I want to download the html file as a word document with page numbers and page breaks(as it has large content). How can I achieve this? My html file is like this

```
<table class="info-table">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:65%;">
                <p>
                    To
                </p>
                <h2><clientname></clientname></h2>
                <p>
                    <clientaddress></clientaddress>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h2>Quotation</h2>
                <p>
                    Quotation No: <quotationno></quotationno> <br />
                    Date: <quotationdate></quotationdate>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Your Reference: <clientrefname></clientrefname> <br />
                    Date: <referencedate></referencedate>

                </p>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: try the open xml sdk from Microsoft https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: is it possible to share the code snippet?